# How to sort naturally in realm.io?

Tags: realm

I have a field "name" (String) with values like "FOO1000", "FOO1100", "FOO150" etc. and use realm-io for Java (Android, 0.89.1)) to get them.

When I use .findAllSorted("name", Sort.ASCENDING) they're not sorted naturally. The output will be

> FOO1000
>   FOO1100
>   FOO150

What I want to achieve is a natural sorting like

> FOO150
>   FOO1000
>   FOO1100

Is there a way to have natural sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Realm uses a standard sorting algoritm. It will sort one character at a time, and since 5 is bigger than 1 it comes last. You can't expect to interpret parts of a string as a number.
If you had 150, 1000, 1100 as a number and sorted that you would get the sort order you expect. If you need to have a string combined with a number you should have FOO0150 instead of FOO150 and it would be sorted as you expect.

Comment: OK, so Realm will use a "natural" sort automatically if i have only numbers? Good to know ;)

Problem is, my values are fixed and I cannot change them. Can you suggest a good / performant way to have my String+Integer values sorted naturally? Maybe run a second sort() on the RealmResult? Is this possible?

Comment: If you want to sort by the number part of your string, you would have to split that out into a separate field and do the sort on that field instead.

Comment: You can call `sort()` multiple times subsequently on RealmResult to define a sort order hierarchy, where each subsequent call will add a new level, which will be applied if there are the same values on the previous levels.

Answer (score -1):

Realm does not have natural sorting by default. Padding the number with leading zeroes will simulate natural sorting.

e.g.

```
Foo 100
Foo 2000
Foo 40
Foo 9
```

Becomes (add more zeroes as you require)

```
Foo 0000100
Foo 0002000
Foo 0000040
Foo 0000009
```

Which yields a naturally sorted output

```
Foo 0000009
Foo 0000040
Foo 0000100
Foo 0002000
```

You may wish to create a new field that stores the padded value separately.